# c# System.Drawing.image IsDisposed Property?

Tags: image, dispose

The System.Drawing.image object in C# does not have the IsDisposed? property.
Is there a way to see IsDisposeds?

Can you tell if an Image object is called Dispose?

Currently, I use it as follows.
I'd like to know if I can possibly avoid using the Try Catch syntax.

```
            try
            {
               var height = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Do you have control over whatever is disposing it?

Comment: An image object isn't supposed to be referenced once disposed. So `IsDisposed` doesn't make any sense there.